# How can I use a linux shell script to change directories and copy files?

Tags: linux, scripting, file-copy

There are several files I need to copy which are stored in different directories. The file names will all have two common fields that are distinctive for a particular date and time.   I can usually refer to them with something like *1155.006*
Basically what I want to do is go to the first directory, tell it to copy the file with *1155.006* to my home directory, change to the next directory and do the same thing etc. 
I will need to name about 5 specific directories so I can't do a blanket grab from all of the sub-directories since that would also net me about 30 files I don't want.
I would also like to get the full name of the files that were copied and write those names to a text file.

I know this is a newbie scripting question so if you can also recommend a good place to start learning scripting commands please send that along.

Comment: Hello and welcome on stackexchange site web dedicated to linux and unix system.
As you will realize, you will probably have very few answer without showing a bit of work. to ask a correct question, you should describe what you want to do, what you have done, what is the expected result, and what is the result you get. You can [edit] your question to add more detail and you can consult the help to ask a better question or directly [this article](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If your dirnames are also unique you can use `$CDPATH`

Comment: @ott - that suggestion is unsafe for several reasons - but first and foremost it is to do with `$IFS`.

Comment: @ott-- Filename wildcards aren't regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5
do
    cp $dir/*1155.006* $HOME
done
```

If you want to log the names of files:

```
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5
do
    for file in $dir/*1155.006*
    do
        cp $file $HOME
        echo "Copied $file" >> log.txt
    done
done
```

Comment: Or just add a `-v` to the cp command in the first for loop. :)   It'd be a good idea to add a `-b` to the `cp` either way, so it'll create backup files if two happen to have the same name.